# Laravel passwordreset error message

Tags: laravel, blocked, error-messaging

I want the blocked user can not perform a password reset link, receive an error message and be forwarded to a page. If a user is blocked, a 2 is stored in the table user, active. How can I do that?

I found thiy code from laravel:

```
/**
     * Send a reset link to the given user.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateEmail($request);

        // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
        // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
        // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
        $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
            $request->only('email')
        );

        return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                    ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($response)
                    : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
    }
```

Comment: from password reset token fetch the user and check `if($user->active == 2) redirect('some_view_page')->with('fail', 'Sorry, your account is blocked');`

Comment: I have to stop sending the email and forward it with an error message. Is the controller ForgotPasswordController correct? Am I doing that with the validation? Or what? I updated my question

Comment: yes, inside this function fetch user by email and check if `$user->active == 2` then redirect with message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to overwrite `sendResetLinkEmail` function, you can just overwrite the `validateEmail` like this

```
protected function validateEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,   

        ['email' => ['required','email',
                      Rule::exists('users')->where(function ($query) {
                        $query->where('active', 1);
                      })
                    ] 
        ]

    );
}
```

**OR**

if you want to redirect to custom url then overwrite `sendResetLinkEmail` function with manual validation like this

```
public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
{

     $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => ['required', 'email',
                         Rule::exists('users')->where(function ($query) {
                             $query->where('active', 1);
                         })
                       ]
             ]);

     if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('some_other_url')
               ->with('fail', 'You can not request reset password, account is block');
     }

    // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
    // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
    // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
    $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
        $request->only('email')
    );

    return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($response)
                : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
}
```

Comment: can i redirect the User directly in this function?

Comment: no, if you want to redirect to some other url then you need to overwrite `sendResetLinkEmail` and create manual validation using make

Comment: Yes, i would like to forward the User and issue an error Message